# How to read another application database in android

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I need to read sqlite database of another application from my application. I know that by default this is not possible within android applications, but as the device is rooted I suppose that I should be able to give my application root access and grab the other application's database and read it.

I don't want the device user to be notified and give me `SUPER_ACCESS` permission, so this should be an anonymous process. The other App has already implemented ContentProvider and has set `exported = true`

This is what I have tried so far but it still throws an exception that it could not open the database file.

```
try {

    File dbFile = new File("/data/data/com.sam.sample/databases/sample.db");

    if(dbFile.exists()) {

        String [] cmd = {"su", "-c", "chmod", "777", file.getPath()};

        Process process = new ProcessBuilder(cmd).start();
        process.waitFor();

        SQLiteDatabase db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(dbFile.getPath(), null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM sample", null);

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
                String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name"));
                    Log.v("FROM DATABASE", name);
                    cursor.moveToNext();
                }
            }
        }

        cursor.close();
        db.close();

    }
}
catch(IOException e) {
   ...
}
```

Is there anything that I am doing wrong here or that I should do differently?

Comment: If the other application has already implemented content provider and has exported it , why dont you use it directly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To read data from other application database, it is necessary that the other application had implemented a `ContentProvider` and had defined that ContentProvider as `exported = true`

For more info about content providers, check out [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html).

Then, to access ContentProvider data you should implement a `ContentResolver` instead of try to access other database directly.

For more info about content receivers, check out [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. ContentProvider is already set to exported = true in the other application, but I am still facing the same issue.